# Is it possible to initialize a double vector with an integer array?

Tags: c++

a is a void pointer, n is the (known) length of the pointer.
I want to use the code below to initialize the value of my double vector with integer pointer. 
Can I directly use the constructor as below or do I have to do another type conversion first?

```
std::vector<double> vec((int*)a[index], (int*)a[index] + n);
```

Comment: are you able to add more code so that we can see the declaration of `a`?

Comment: *n is the (known) length of the pointer* -- This is not clear what `n` actually is.  Is it the number of integers?  The number of bytes?

Comment: Where did you get `index` from?

Comment: Why are you conflating two ideas here?  1) the ideas of initializing a vector of doubles from an array of ints and 2) the idea of getting the address of your integer array from the `index`th element an array of `void*`'s  Your question should have a single focus.

Comment: You are using the **range constructor** - that's fine.  Do you need an explanation of why the range constructor can be used with bare pointers, (to obtain input iterators from int*'s implicitly) or why the conversion from double to int occurs implicitly?  Does it just seem too magical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all yuou should not use C style cast in C++ as it is less readable and more dangerous. Second - it is not clear where you got this variable `index` from and why you think you need it. One possible way is (assuming that `a` just points to `int` array of size `n`):

```
auto ia = static_cast<int *>( a );
std::vector<double> vec( ia, ia + n);
```

of course you can make it more verbose:

```
std::vector<double> vec( static_cast<int *>( a ), static_cast<int *>( a ) + n);
```

but it is not a good idea either.

Comment: To be consistent with the original question I think either you should have `std::vector<double vec(ia + index, ia + index + n);`  Or you should have written `auto ia = static_cast<int *>(a) + index;`

Comment: @Wyck I do not think I can be consistent in this sense - current code is incorrect and it is not clear what `index` is doing here at all. And as i said I wrote code assuming `index` is irrelevant here. If OP clarifies I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a[index]` names an array of at least `n` `int`s, then

```
std::vector<double> vec((int*)a[index], (int*)a[index] + n);
```

does indeed initialise `vec` with `n` `double`s copied from those `int`s